# How can I ensure that my ASP.NET web app is served through https when running it from .exe

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I deployed my full stack app with a React frontend and an ASP.NET API to a shared folder on my machine. I can run the .exe that is in the build folder and it serves my web app to localhost through http & https like shown in this window [image]
However when my colleague runs the same application on his machine it does not show the https link. Any idea if there is an additional package he may need to install in order to serve the app on https? I can't imagine any other reason why the app would run differently on different machines.

Comment: Why are you running it as an EXE? Microsoft's recommendation on Windows is to use IIS to host/run your ASP.NET app. Is this ASP.NET Core, or the legacy ASP.NET stack?

Comment: Its ASP.NET Core, I would normally deploy to IIS but this is a temporary work around due to other issues.. just cant figure out why it works on my machine but not on his

Comment: We use different tags for ASP.NET Core. And your question has nothing to do with React.

Comment: it works when I launch it in development mode in IIS through Visual studio. Is there a way I can deploy IIS locally and use it like that?

Comment: Sure, you can run IIS locally.

Comment: The endpoints can be overridden in several ways, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration So if you really want HTTPS and on a dedicate port, forbid overriding and hard code to whatever you like (or host on IIS to set up site bindings there).

Comment: thanks @LexLi the first sentence on that link allowed me to figure out the issue.. ```https://localhost:5001 (when a local development certificate is present)``` so clearly my colleagues dont have the same local development cert that I do